# What type of math or programming problen is this

Tags: php, math

I have already solved this (see code below) but I don't have a satisfactory name for the resulting function.Also, I would like to explore this problem more broadly but I do not know what I am searching for. I have tried "circular math", "clock problem" I even remember monads being used to address this principle but I cannot find where I saw that.

THE PROBLEM: Given an sequential set of numbers that go in a circle like a clock `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4..` (or a color hue scale in my case) and given a distance (in integers) I want to calculate the resulting number on that circular series.
So if a clock shows 5 and I add 9 hours the result should be 2.

`5+9=2` or `3-7=8`

The question is what do I call this. Here it's the solution in PHP:

```
function circularmath($strExpression = "2+2" , $top = 355 ){
$result = 0;
if(preg_match('/^\d+[+-]\d+$/',$strExpression)){
    list($n1,$op,$n2)=preg_split('/([+-])/',$strExpression, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $result =($op==="+")? $n1+$n2:$n1-$n2;
    if($result < 0){
        $result=$top+$result;
    }elseif($result > $top){
        $result=$result-$top;
    }
  }
 return $result;
}

$foo = circularmath("352+4");
echo $foo;
```

Comment: Are you looking for modular arithmetic?

Comment: [Modular Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) is exactly *the term* you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thomas G and ggorlen. It is in fact Modular Arithmetic and it led to better code:

```
        function mod($a, $n) {
            return ($a % $n) + ($a < 0 ? $n : 0);
        }
        function circularmath($strExpression = "2+2" , $top = 355 ){
            $result = null;
            if(preg_match('/^\d+[+-]\d+$/',$strExpression)){
                list($n1,$op,$n2)=preg_split('/([+-])/',$strExpression, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
                $result =($op==="+")? $n1+$n2:$n1-$n2;
                $result = mod($result , $top) ;
            }
        return $result;
        }
        $foo = circularmath("352+4")."\n";
        echo "f:".$foo;
```